# PHPmailer stuck on mail.php AND being marked as spam issue

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've got an issue with PHPmailer getting stuck on my mail.php screen (usually it forwards the user to a success.html page). I've turned on error reporting, but still nothing shows up. I'm quite a noob at PHP, but it was working on my test URL before I moved it to the actual URL I wanted it to be on (just a few directories over on my server). Now I'm stuck on a white screen with no errors.

ALSO, I'm having an issue where on hotmail (and maybe some other providers--Gmail is working fine now) it's marking the emails as spam. I fixed a reverse DNS issue, but it's still marking the emails as spam. Any ideas on how to fix it? Please check my body and see if the content raises any red flags.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('/var/www/includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

//gather variables from form//
$gmname =   $_POST['gmname'];
$charname = $_POST['charname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$bantype = $_POST['radiogroup'];
$banreason = $_POST['banreason'];
//end gather//

$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$body             ="Attention account holder,<br \>This is a notice informing you that your Ashran account has been suspended. Please review the following information.<br \><br \>Account Name: $email<br \>Character Name: $charname<br \>Server: US - Grommash<br \>Ban Reason: $banreason<br \>Ban Type: $bantype<br \>Ban End Date: $date $time Server Time<br \>Banning staff member: $gmname<br \><br \>If you would like to appeal your ban because you feel that you were incorrectly punished, please follow the instructions in the following thread: <a href="http://forum.ashran.com/index.php?/topic/9461-ban-appeals/#entry68417">Click Here</a><br \><br \>Do NOT reply to this email.";
//$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);//

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 //   sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "----------@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "----------";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('----------@gmail.com', '------ -----');

$mail->AddReplyTo("---------@gmail.com","----- -----");

$mail->Subject    = "Ashran - Account Suspension Notice";

//$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "$email";
$mail->AddAddress($address);

//Sets URL for forward after completion
$url = 'success.html';
//

if(!$mail->Send()) {

    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 

} else {

    header( "Location: $url" );
    echo "Ban notice sent!!!";
}
```

?>

Comment: to start remove output buttering

Comment: Ok, done. It said to do that for the redirect. Didn't fix anything, though. Same result.

Comment: Your code looks ok, though it looks like you've based it on an old example - are you using latest PHPMailer? Like Dagon said, you only need output buffering if you're not paying attention to what you're doing! That "Ban notice sent" will never show because it happens after the redirect. You can check the redirect by using your browser's dev tools. Is there anything in success.html?

Comment: @Synchro Yes, success.html just has a basic:
<h1>Ban notice sent!</h1>
I'm aware that the echo version of it wouldn't show, that was leftover from before I had the redirect.

I'm using the latest PHPMailer, yes, but it was working fine until I migrated it to the other site on my server. PM me and I can give you a link to the live form if you want.

Could it be a permissions issue? I think they're all 775.
EDIT: Also, I moved it back to it's original spot and it's not working still... hmm

Comment: Comment out the redirect and set `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;`. That should make it noisier!

Comment: @Synchro Nope, as I said it's not sending so it's not redirecting (it's in the else statement). Still a white screen after doing both of those things :/

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: In that case you must be getting an internal server error that's resulting in the white screen, so check the HTTP code that your browser is getting (in dev tools) and check your web server's error log. Failing that, add `echo 'x'; exit;` to the first line of your file, and move it down until it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the spam folder issue: If you find you're in a process where you're tweaking your content and then checking if it fixed your delivery problems, you can use inboxtrail.com's seed-based email deliverability test to see which email providers are dumping you to the spam folder after each content change. It's probably a good idea to re-test all the top providers, since for all you know a content change that solves the problem on hotmail could create new problems on gmail or yahoo or something. This should also tell you if the way your email server is configured is setting off any red flags.